# Why is there gravity in the pod bay on Discovery One in 2001 and 2010 movies?

Tags: 2001-a-space-odyssey, artificial-gravity, 2010-odyssey-two

In both movies, [2001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey_(film)) and [2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_(film)), we see people **walking** in the pod hangar bay aboard the *[Discovery One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovery_One)*. The only part of the ship that has artificial gravity is the centrifuge wheel, so *how can people walk in the pod hangar bay?*

David Bowman and Frank Poole seem to walk normally through the hangar. They don't need to steady themselves as they walk in a supposedly zero gravity environment.

(Sorry about posting a link to the entire movie. I could not find a clip of just that scene. Fast forward to 1:02:30.)

Their walking motions are very unlike the slow and cautious walking motions of the woman in this scene from the movie, 2001. Kubrick made a point of showing us her "grip shoes" so we can how she walks on a surface while in zero gravity.

In the movie, 2010, Heywood Floyd also walks normally through the octagon hallway into the hangar bay. (Fast forward to 2:37.)

We know [Kubrick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley_Kubrick) was a stickler for getting the details right. Was this an oversight on his part?

Comment: Simulating zero-g is expensive (and not always convincing). My guess is that Kubrick (and whoever produced 2010) hoped that people wouldn't notice.

Comment: They appear to be walking in a very stilted way, placing each foot carefully on the ground before leaning into the next step.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing as @Valorum. They both look very stiff when walking in the hangar, and they appear to be wearing some funky shoes and walking on some black floor coating.

Comment: As for the *2010* clip: Kubrick wasn't involved in the movie, so any oversights are not his.

Comment: @Mick But Kubrick did pay attention to zero-g in other scenes, and like RichS said, he was a stickler for detail, so that's unlikely the reason :)

Comment: They have black pads on the floor which I presume are grip pads, and maybe experienced astronauts would get used to walking on them, but they way they walk up the steps into the pod gives the game away. Funny thing is, I've seen this movie dozens of times and *never noticed*. I'm guessing it was a budget choice and they deliberately eased the viewer into the astronauts acting more and more normally.

Comment: @AndresF. There are other technical inaccuracies that may have been made for convenience or aesthetic reasons, rather than being genuine errors. One such is the Aries Shuttle approach to the space station. As seen from the station dock, the shuttle should have spiralled in on the rotational axis, but it doesn't. It may have been a genuine error, or it may have been done deliberately to avoid confusing the audience.

Answer (score 11):

If you watch the *2001* clip more carefully, you can see that most of the time, the actors are walking with a very stilted step (also mentioned in comments). Either the floor, or their shoes, are magnetized, which would be more practical than velcro for an environment that isn't carpeted. Nearly every scene in the pod bay in *2001* has them walking the same way, with a couple of exceptions (including a shift in stance in the scene you reference above) that are clearly errors that weren't worth going back and correcting.

For *2010*, Peter Hyams was not trying to copy Kubrick's style, and chose not to dwell as much on the details of life in space. For example *Alexei Leonov* has a rotating section, but we see people walking normally, without stilted, prying feet off the floor walk of magnetized shoes, even in the parts of the ships that aren't under spin, like the bridge of *Leonov* or the pod bay of *Discovery*. However, two scenes clearly simulate realistic low-grav inside the ships -- Chandra in HAL's central processing unit, and Floyd using floating pens to demonstrate his idea for using *Discovery* to boost *Leonov*. These scenes demonstrate fairly clearly that Hyams knows there shouldn't be gravity in the non-spin sections, and that he simply chose not to have actors walk funny to belabour the point. There's a somewhat greater attention to such details during the exterior spacewalk scenes, however, including the use of the portable thruster and tether when Max and Curnow jump across to *Discovery*.

Comment: Your answer, while plausible, seems like speculation unless you have links to or quotes from original sources. Can you provide links or quotes to support your answer?

Comment: @RichS, he's describing scenes and things you can see, not quoting sources.

Answer (score 4):

They have velcro on their shoes.

> The stewardess came walking up the narrow corridor to the right of the closely spaced seats. There was a slight buoyancy about her steps, and her feet came away from the floor reluctantly as if entangled in glue. She was keeping to the bright yellow band of Velcro carpeting that ran the full length of the floor - and of the ceiling... This trick of walking in free fall was immensely reassuring to disoriented passengers.

Ironically, this was actually tried in real life and astronauts just ended up tripping over their own feet and found that weightlessness isn't the impediment it seemed back then.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have a source for their shoes being equipped with Velcro as opposed to magnets as the previous answer suggests?  The rest of your answer is a comment, and not an answer; please read [answer] to learn to write better answers.  Follow-on answers should provide additional details not covered by existing answers.

Comment: http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/content.asp?Bnum=1368 quotes it from the book: "The stewardess came walking up the narrow corridor to the right of the closely spaced seats. There was a slight buoyancy about her steps, and her feet came away from the floor reluctantly as if entangled in glue. She was keeping to the bright yellow band of Velcro carpeting that ran the full length of the floor - and of the ceiling... This trick of walking in free fall was immensely reassuring to disoriented passengers."

Comment: You should add that to the answer.